# cmd overlay enable <package name> resets to it's previous state after reboot

Tags: reboot, android-11, aosp, navigation-bar, overlay

I'm trying to switch between `gestural` and `threebutton` navigation using

`cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.gestural`

and

`cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.threebutton`

or via `system-->gestures-->system navigation` and then selecting `gesture navigation` and `3-button navigation`.

I checked the changes using -
`cmd overlay list --user current`  and I was able to see the exact changes made.

But when i reboot my android device, it just reverts back to the previous selected navigation; rarely (after 5-6 tries) the changes made remain after reboot.

Example: If my present selection is threebutton and I change it to gestural, then after reboot it goes back to threebutton or sometimes (after 5-6 tries and reboots), it stays as gestural.

How do i keep the changes permanent even after reboot??

Comment: Hello. Which Android device are you using?

Comment: @Firelord: Hi, It's a custom ROM with android 11.